# dynamically created button click event is not working in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to call dynamically created button click event. I this event I want to show one message on clicking dynamically created button.

my Code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button btnNew = new Button();
        btnNew.ID = "btnClick";
        btnNew.Text = "Click";

        btnNew.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnNew_Click);
        this.form1.Controls.Add(btnNew);

    }
    protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblMeaaseg = new Label();
        lblMeaaseg.ID = "txtMessage";
        lblMeaaseg.Text = "Hello Shree";
        this.form1.Controls.Add(lblMeaaseg);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  As you will quickly learn, "doesn't work" is not a valid description of what is wrong with your code.  Please provide the exact text of the error you are receiving and the line where it is occurring, as applicable

Comment: I want to show this lblMessage on btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) event but it is not working

Comment: You may have to add location of the label.

Comment: this.form1.Controls.Add(lblMeaaseg); this is location that I want to display the label

Comment: @RyanDansie - what does it have to do with ViewState?

Comment: @RyanDansie - the problem here is not in the ViewState, but in the fact the control that is supposed to fire server-side click event does not exist.

Comment: @RyanDansie - you are mistaken - ViewState does not re-create server controls. Nor does ASP.NET automatically re-create dynamic controls based on ViewState.

Comment: @Igor sorry yes you are right about creating controls. Viewstate is only relevant for restoring properties of the control after a post back. Comments retracted.

Comment: I added this line  btnNew.Attributes.Add("runat", "server"); for accessing like server side control. still it is not working.

Comment: @Shree - because it is a wrong thing to do. Dynamically created control is already server-side control, not to mention that runat="server" only has meaning in markup.

Answer (score 1):

You create the dynamic button in the click event handler of `btnMain` during the postback caused by `btnMain` click. After that you see the new button in the browser page, click it and expect its click event handler (`btnNew_Click`) to fire. Pressing the new dynamic button causes a new postback that is processed by a new instance of the page created on the server by ASP.NET. This new page does not have the dynamic button - there is nothing there connected to `btnNew_Click`. You have to write code that persists the fact that the dynamic button has been created and recreates this button every time the page is instantiated. So that this button has a chance to feel and respond to its client-side click.